# Running kernel mode syscalls from user mode

Tags: c, assembly, kernel, ida

I was trying to read the memory of certain processes like csrss.exe using `OpenProcess()`. The problem is that, as soon as I use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` these processes can't be opened. So I tried using `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` parameter and that doesn't fetch juicy results.

From my understanding of the system, this function ultimately calls `ZwOpenProcess()`. My current understanding is that, if it is being accessed by an application in the user mode, this call will also be treated as call from the user mode and not the kernel mode.

To bypass this check, I did the following:

1. Used IDA to open `ntdll.dll` where all these processes are present.
2. Find the function, and here is what I found.

[image: Cap_1]
So again from my understanding, it performs a test, then if it evaluates to 0, it executes the low latency system call, which I believe is the Kernel Mode Version of the function.

Next I did the same for `ZwReadVirtualMemory()`:
[image: Cap_2]

So here are my questions:

1. Can I directly make a .asm file and write these procedures in the same and call them to get kernel mode access to these functions?
2. Will `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` work for these routines if I call them using the above method.
3. I also need to use `VirtualQueryEx()` for which I couldn't find a kernel mode replacement, in that case, I plan to use `VirtualQueryEx()` along with the above mentioned custom calls. Now my question here is that, since `VirtualQueryEx()` is not a kernel mode call(not on the top atleast, by that I mean `ReadProcessMemory()` also calls ZwReadVirtualMemory but isn't a kernel mode call if initiated by user mode program, so is the case with `VirtualQueryEx()`), will it be a problem or will it revert back to user mode when I make the next custom call?

The ultimate agenda of myself doing all this is to be able to open all processes with kernel level privileges, read their memory and dump them into a file. This also includes processes that are running at system level like csrss.exe. If any easier approach exists, kindly enlighten me with the same.

```
Code :

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
HANDLE lProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
DWORD error = GetLastError();

if (hProc || lProc)
    {


            //(!hProc && lProc) ? printf("lproc") : printf("hProc"); //Testing Condition
            fProc = (!hProc && lProc) ? lProc : hProc;

        while (1) {
            if ((VirtualQueryEx(fProc, addr1, &meminfo, sizeof(meminfo))) == 0)
            {
                break;
            }


            if ((meminfo.State == MEM_COMMIT))
            {
                static unsigned char display_buffer[1024 * 128];
                SIZE_T bytes_left;
                SIZE_T total_read;
                SIZE_T bytes_to_read;
                SIZE_T bytes_read;
                FILE *f;


                    f = fopen("Dump.txt", "a");


                addr = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress;

                //printf("Process Name : %ws\r\n", pName.Buffer);
                fprintf(f, "Process Name : %ws\r\n", pName.Buffer);

                //printf("Base Address : 0x%08x\r\n", addr);
                fprintf(f, "Base Address : 0x%08x\r\n", addr);

                bytes_left = meminfo.RegionSize;

                //printf("Region Size : %d\r\n", bytes_left);
                fprintf(f, "Region Size : %d\r\n", bytes_left);

                total_read = 0;

                //printf("Contents : \r\n");
                fprintf(f, "Contents : \r\n");

                while (bytes_left)
                {
                    bytes_to_read = (bytes_left > sizeof(display_buffer)) ? sizeof(display_buffer) : bytes_left;
                    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, addr + total_read, display_buffer, bytes_to_read, &bytes_read);
                    if (bytes_read != bytes_to_read) break;

                    int j = 0;


                    for (j = 0; j < bytes_to_read; j++)
                    {
                        if ((display_buffer[j] > 31) && (display_buffer[j] < 127)) {
                            //printf("%c ", display_buffer[j]);
                            fprintf(f, "%c", display_buffer[j]);
                        }
                        else {
                            //printf(".");
                            fprintf(f, ".");
                        }
                    }
                    //printf("\r\n");
                    fprintf(f, "\r\n");

                    bytes_left -= bytes_read;
                    total_read += bytes_read;
                }

                fclose(f);

            }

            addr1 = (unsigned char*)meminfo.BaseAddress + meminfo.RegionSize;

        }

    }

        else {

        printf("\nFailed to open process - error - %d\r\n", error);

    }
```

So, here I'm trying to save all the memory information to a DUMP.txt file for a given process.

Comment: So you're planning new spyware?

Comment: Actually no. I wanna make a memory scanner which scans all programs. Sort of like a hex editor for all processes.

Comment: There is _nothing_ you can do from outside the kernel that will cause either `ZwOpenProcess` or `NtOpenProcess` to be treated as a kernel-mode operation.  This is by design and intended to prevent people from doing the exact thing you are trying to do.  You _may_, however, be able to bypass these protections by writing an actual kernel-mode driver and getting it loaded into the actual kernel.

Comment: That's the problem right there. In x64 based Windows, you need a signed driver. Exactly why I was trying to run custom routines without the use of the test and jump functionalities. Not sure if it works. Its just an idea that struck me.

Comment: To be clear, you did not find the "is this call coming from user mode" check by dumping the code of `ntdll.dll`.  You found what appears to be a runtime switch between two equivalent ways of trapping into the kernel; `syscall` is newer and faster than `int xxh`.  The actual check is inside `ntoskrnl.exe` or whatever it's called these days.  Get yourself a copy of _Windows Internals_ and read it cover to cover.  (_Undocumented Windows_ is probably also worth reading, although it's many years out of date.)

Comment: Ok, also, if I'm able to bypass that check somehow. The one you mentioned which exists in ntoskrnl.exe, will I be able to achievement kernel mode from within user mode. So basically I follow the whole chain of events, manually code it, and skip that one check and run the final procedure. Is that possible?

Comment: Also, you _might_ be able to disable the protections on programs running with SYSTEM credentials by switching on [kernel debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/setting-up-local-kernel-debugging-of-a-single-computer-manually).  I don't know exactly how that works, but I do know that WinDbg can show you all sorts of operating system data structures if you do that, so it's bypassing those protections _somehow_...

Comment: I don't think I can help you any further.  I'm not really a Windows guru.

Comment: I did get SEDbgPrivilege. That doesn't seem to help. Would help if I get any heads up on how WinDbg achieves it.

Comment: WinDbg enables the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege in the access token of the user running it. It probably also self-elevate (I always disable UAC notifications but I'd expect one) in case the user is a Protected Admin. Beware: AdjustTokenPrivileges *doesn't* fail for privileges not present in the token. It seems impossible from the API to add a privilege to a token (they are inherited from the user at the creation of the token or stripped off). If you make your application self-elevate or just run it as Administrator, you will be able to set SE_DEBUG_NAME and open another local process.

Comment: Running it as an administrator + using SE_DEBUG_NAME, still can't get PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS for a lot of system processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Windows Vista - Windows 10

Thanks to [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472490/running-kernel-mode-syscalls-from-user-mode/50534940?noredirect=1#comment88100586_50534940) for pointing out that since Windows 10, things changed.
Actually, they started changing since Windows Vista.

Windows Vista introduced the concept of [protected process](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=34) to
enforce the application of the DRM to media content.
A protected process cannot be read or modified by a normal process (besides other restrictions).
Protected processes can only be loaded if signed and only if they perform only a restricted set of
operations.

With Windows 8.1 Microsoft revisited the protected processes and introduced the Protected Process Light
(PPL) class of process.
A PPL can only be started by another PPL; with secure-boot or with a [specific registry key/environment variable](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=97) the critical system processes are PPL.
This means they cannot be opened, even by admin/system account.

`csrss.exe` is also a PPL since Windows 8.1:

> Note that it’s interesting that Csrss.exe was blessed with a protection level as well. It isn’t responsible for launching any special protected processes and doesn’t have any interesting data in memory like LSASS or the System process do. It has, however, gained a very nefarious reputation in recent years as being the source of multiple Windows exploits

Each process, besides its protection level, also has a *signer*.
This fields specifies how the process is truested in the system.
The values are:

```
PsProtectedSignerNone = 0n0
PsProtectedSignerAuthenticode = 0n1
PsProtectedSignerCodeGen = 0n2
PsProtectedSignerAntimalware = 0n3
PsProtectedSignerLsa = 0n4
PsProtectedSignerWindows = 0n5
PsProtectedSignerWinTcb = 0n6
PsProtectedSignerMax/PsProtectedSignerWinSystem = 0n7
```

Finally, each signer type has a structure determining:

1. With other types of signers are allowed to open the process.
2. Two access mask to specify which privileges are not allowed when trying to open the process.

Each signer but the `PsProtectedSignerNone` limits the privileges to

```
PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME
PROCESS_TERMINATE (excluding WinTcb, Antimalware and Lsa)
PROCESS_SET_LIMITED_INFORMATION
```

In order to open `csrss.exe` its necessary run the requestion process as a protected process with the appropriate
signer but this require the binary [to be signed](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=146) by Microsoft.
Alternatively, [as RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50472490/running-kernel-mode-syscalls-from-user-mode/50534940?noredirect=1#comment88102968_50534940) pointed out, if you can load a kernel driver, it's possible to temper with the `EPROCESS` structure, altering the protection level bits.

---

## Windows 7

This very simple program opens a process started by SYSTEM.

```
#include <windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    HANDLE thisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE thisToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES newPrivileges;
    HANDLE thatProcess;
    
    newPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    newPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    
    if (LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, "SeDebugPrivilege", &newPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid) == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "LookupPrivilegeValue", "Cannot find privilege", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        ExitProcess(1);     
    }
    
    if (OpenProcessToken(thisProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &thisToken) == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "OpenProcessToken", "Cannot open token", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        ExitProcess(2);
    }
    
    AdjustTokenPrivileges(thisToken, FALSE, &newPrivileges, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "AdjustTokenPrivileges", "Cannot adjust privileges", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        ExitProcess(3);
    }
    
    thatProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 1080);
    
    if (thatProcess == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "OpenProcess", "Cannot open that process", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        ExitProcess(4);
    }
    
    MessageBox(NULL, "Done", "Opened", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    
}
```

When run under an account which has the *SeDebugPrivilege*, such as an administrator account, it succeeds in getting the process handle.
When not run under the condition of above it fails at the `AdjustTokenPrivileges` step.
I tested it on my system, running it as both a full-fledged admin and as a normal user. Only the admin could open it.

It works as I explained in my previous comment: it enables the *SeDebugPrivilege* in its access token and then opens an arbitrary system process handle.

**Note** The process id is hardcoded, change it.

One important thing to understand is that `AdjustTokenPrivileges` *cannot add* new privileges, it can only enable/disable the privileges the process inherits from the user.
As far as I know, there is no public API to add a new privilege to an access token.
If the program is run under a non-administrative user the process will fail because [no sane admin will grant such a powerful privilege to any non-admin](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080314-00/?p=23113).

Also, even if your account is an administrative one, you are probably running as a [protected administrator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742497(v=vs.85).aspx) and thus the token assigned to a process won't have `SeDebugPrivilege`.

You can fix this by either running as full administrator or by [self-elevating the process](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppUACSelfElevation-981c0160).

---

> My current understanding is that, if it is being accessed by an application in the user mode, this call will also be treated as call from the user mode and not the kernel mode.

This understanding is incorrect.
The kernel in inaccessible from userspace, there is an [entry-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) that transfers control from the user space to the kernel but a user program cannot read/write the kernel memory.
Every important information about the system, including handles, are kept in the kernel, away from the user programs reach.

When a program uses a system call to transition into the kernel it also relinquishes control to the kernel; simply put you can execute a designed kernel function but you cannot read/write its code or data.
This is an architectural (read CPU) constraint, it's very robust even though loopholes are routinely found to bypass it.
If you are looking for such a loophole, you are looking for a [zero-day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_(computing)) vulnerability.
A bug in the OS.

The access rights check is, obviously, performed by the kernel code, so you cannot see, touch or circumvent it unless you make a program part of the kernel.
This is a [driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver), you can develop one with the [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) (as opposed to the SDK).
Loading drivers still require administrative privileges but an admin, or a privileged setup, can make the driver load at startup (they are kind of services, they don't need a user).
Actually a service should suffice in this case.

**The check you are seeing in the disassembly** is just a compatibility path, Windows uses the `syscall` instruction as opposed to the legacy `int 2eh`.
I thought the legacy mechanism was gone.
Both paths will eventually merge in the kernel.

> So again from my understanding, it performs a test, then if it evaluates to 0, it executes the low latency system call, which I believe is the Kernel Mode Version of the function

This is incorrect as explained above.
You can sense that it cannot possibly be true because there is no code in both paths (where is the non-kernel mode version of the function?).

---

> Can I directly make a .asm file and write these procedures in the same and call them to get kernel mode access to these functions?

The code invokes the system call directly, this interface is private.
Microsoft reserves to itself the right to change the system calls' numbers and/or the calling convention.
Only the public API is stable across different version of Windows.
If you want, you can invoke the system call directly by doing:

```
mov r10, rcx
mov eax, 26h
syscall
```

and then setting the parameter in the registers the way you would for `NtOpenProcess`.
You wouldn't get anywhere though, this is just an inlined, non-portable, version of the original function.

> Will PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS work for these routines if I call them using the above method.

No, the check is still performed by the kernel.

> I also need to use VirtualQueryEx() for which I couldn't find a kernel mode replacement, in that case, I plan to use VirtualQueryEx() along with the above mentioned custom calls. Now my question here is that, since VirtualQueryEx() is not a kernel mode call(not on the top atleast, by that I mean ReadProcessMemory() also calls ZwReadVirtualMemory but isn't a kernel mode call if initiated by user mode program, so is the case with VirtualQueryEx()), will it be a problem or will it revert back to user mode when I make the next custom call?

I cannot fully understand this question, I'm sorry for that.
All I can say is that: a) The WinAPIs and the private API are two different sets of APIs b) The WinAPIs don't use the private APIs in a 1:1 fashion, they may involve more than one system call (Fun fact: It seems that Windows uses system calls even for code already at ring 0) c) All privileged actions are executed by the kernel, this is not at the choice of the invoking program.

> The ultimate agenda of myself doing all this is to be able to open all processes with kernel level privileges, read their memory and dump them into a file. This also includes processes that are running at system level like csrss.exe. If any easier approach exists, kindly enlighten me with the same.

The kernel has no privilege, users have privileges and thus so have processes.
You should be able to dump any user-mode process with a program running either as an admin or a service running as System.

Comment: `mov eax, 26h` / `syscall`: which version of Windows does this work on?  I think you should make a bigger deal about this being non-portable and unsupported, instead of starting by saying "you can do this to make a system call".

Comment: @PeterCordes, you are right. I'm editing it. Thank you!

Comment: I followed what you said, but there are some processes like csrss.exe that cannot be dumped. It can be opened by PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION but it cannot be opened with PROCESS_ALL _ACCESS. I was looking for a method to open such processes with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS to dump their memory and the only option which I was left with was to make kernel level calls. Is there any other way to open csrss.exe with PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS?

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion I'll run another test and report the results.

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion I can open csrss.exe on my system (Windows 7)

Comment: Windows 10 x64 and cannot open csrss.exe. actually I can open it with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION but there is no data in the buffer. Its just blank spaces.

Comment: @TotalAnimeImmersion I only tested if `OpenProcess` return successfully. I won't be able to get my hand on a Win10 PC until Monday. If you get blanks maybe it is because you are using the API incorrectly?

Comment: I'll post the code I'm using soon for you to verify. Also you could check if the same works on a windows 10 PC

Comment: you not take to account that in latest windows version - *csrss.exe* is protected process - `PsProtectedTypeProtectedLight.PsProtectedSignerWinTcb` - any debug privilege not help in this. only another protected process with the same or higher protection level can open protected process with full access. otherwise - maximum which we can got `SYNHRONIZE |  PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access

Comment: Windows 7 - yes. you can - because here csrss yet not protected process. but begin from 8.1 - you already not open csrss with this code

Comment: @RbMm Thank you very much, I'll read that link and update my answer. Thanks again!

Comment: in win10 added `PsProtectedSignerWinSystem = 7` protected signer, now only `System` process have this signer. after usual access check - system compare access mask with `RTL_PROTECTED_ACCESS.DeniedProcessAccess` and if intersect - do additional check [`RtlTestProtectedAccess`](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/RtlTestProtectedAccess.png) - with debug privs - maximum which we can get (for not intersect this mask) - `SYNCHRONIZE|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_SET_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME`. also if use `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` - it always failed

Comment: mask for `PsProtectedSignerWinSystem` - `0xFEFFF` so only `SYNHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access possible for that process (System) get info about protection level we can with `PS_PROTECTION ps;

     if (0 <= NtQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessProtectionInformation, &ps, sizeof(ps), &rcb)`

Comment: @RbMm If I understood the linked articles correctly, only a protected process with signer WinSystem can open the system processes. And to run such a protected process, a signature from Microsoft is required. Is that right? (thanks!)

Comment: required not less protection level. say for open (or debug) `PsProtectedSignerWinTcb` we must have `PsProtectedSignerWinTcb` or `PsProtectedSignerWinSystem` (i forget - *Memory Compression* is also `PsProtectedSignerWinSystem` ). for open say `PsProtectedSignerAntimalware` need be not less than `PsProtectedSignerAntimalware` and so on. also for open `PsProtectedTypeProtectedLight` we need be too `PsProtectedTypeProtectedLight` or `PsProtectedTypeProtected`. for open `PsProtectedTypeProtected` need be only `PsProtectedTypeProtected`. of course all this in case if we require access intersect

Comment: with `RTL_PROTECTED_ACCESS.DeniedProcessAccess`. and yes - for normal create protected process need have sign exe (i never try this). however possible from kernel driver found `PS_PROTECTION` offset in `EPROCESS` without hard-code this (even for vista where here only 1 bit) and temporary make any process protected. after this it can open another protected. i use this trick in some self tools